# Libreoffice Calc group monthly values to get chart

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with payments per month, each month there are multiple payments. How can I group monthly payments to display them as a chart

Example:

```
----------------------------
| Month   | Payment        |
----------------------------
| 2018-01 | 120            |
| 2018-01 |  80            |
| 2018-01 | 200            |
| 2018-02 | 240            |
| 2018-02 | 210            |
| 2018-02 | 195            |
| 2018-02 | 150            |
----------------------------
```

This would produce a chart like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pivot the data (Row Fields: Month, Data Fields: Sum - Payment) and use that as the source for an area chart:

[image: SO50325996 example]